# Client/Server relationship for CBT in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, client

I was wondering if it is possible to create a client/server VB.net app that has a method of retrieving questions randomly from a server running a server version of the APP. I am trying to create a Computer Based Testing application. Thanks

Comment: You will just have to make a Database table with Question, Answers and TypeOfAnswer (Radiobutton, textbox etc.)
And then when you're writing a query for result set you will just make it to appear all randomly. According to your TypeOfAnswer you will make couple of cases for WinForm view and that would be it. 
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I actually know that Nidzaaa. I cannot say i totally understand what you mean by making a couple of cases for WinForm View. Is there not a need for server connection first? How does a client CBT app connect to the server CBT app running on a designated server PC? (This must run on a Local Area Network) and the server must be the repository of questions, timing and evaluation.

Comment: There is no need for a server app. The client app would make a connection to the db directly. The classes mentioned would deal with different answer types eg radio button (multi choice one answer), checkboxes (multi choice more than one choice required) etc. The client app would also have an admin section to allow an admin to add/change questions

Comment: Thanks Mych. I totally understand now. ARE there references you may have for me though to better understand the concept? Pls picture this. All computers (About 20) must retrieve questions from the same source. timing, populating and depopulating database with questions and must also be determined centrally on a PC which is why i felt the need for server app would be important.